# How to grab two pieces of data from Stripe Event object using webhooks and put into PHP variables?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm sure this is incredibly simple, but I don't see it in the Stripe documentation (probably bc it is incredibly simple haha).

I created a webhook in Stripe for "charge.succeeed". I sent it as a test and I get the following information.  If I just wanted to get the customer value (i.e. "customer": "cus_00000000000000",) and the amount value (i.e. "amount": 888,) into PHP variables (to later put into my database) how would I get those?

```
"{
      "created": 1326853478,
      "livemode": false,
      "id": "evt_00000000000000",
      "type": "charge.succeeded",
      "object": "event",
      "request": null,
      "pending_webhooks": 1,
      "api_version": "2017-12-14",
      "data": {
        "object": {
          "id": "ch_00000000000000",
          "object": "charge",
          "amount": 888,
          "amount_refunded": 0,
          "application": null,
          "application_fee": null,
          "balance_transaction": "txn_00000000000000",
          "captured": true,
          "created": 1516049428,
          "currency": "usd",
          "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
          "description": "ettet",
          "destination": null,
          "dispute": null,
          "failure_code": null,
          "failure_message": null,
          "fraud_details": {
          },
          "invoice": null,
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {
          },
          "on_behalf_of": null,
          "order": null,
          "outcome": {
            "network_status": "approved_by_network",
            "reason": null,
            "risk_level": "normal",
            "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
            "type": "authorized"
          },
          "paid": true,
          "receipt_email": "garysaldutti@gmail.com",
          "receipt_number": null,
          "refunded": false,
          "refunds": {
            "object": "list",
            "data": [

            ],
            "has_more": false,
            "total_count": 0,
            "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1BkeuWANnSPS4xkeDo0R8j3T/refunds"
          },
          "review": null,
          "shipping": null,
          "source": {
            "id": "card_00000000000000",
            "object": "card",
            "address_city": null,
            "address_country": null,
            "address_line1": null,
            "address_line1_check": null,
            "address_line2": null,
            "address_state": null,
            "address_zip": null,
            "address_zip_check": null,
            "brand": "Visa",
            "country": "US",
            "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
            "cvc_check": "pass",
            "dynamic_last4": null,
            "exp_month": 4,
            "exp_year": 2020,
            "fingerprint": "Iksh1TPp3lc5HM4c",
            "funding": "credit",
            "last4": "4242",
            "metadata": {
            },
            "name": null,
            "tokenization_method": null
          },
          "source_transfer": null,
          "statement_descriptor": null,
          "status": "succeeded",
          "transfer_group": null
        }
      }
    }"
```

Below is how I would handle/retrieve the data above, just not sure how to get those two specific things into PHP variables...

```
// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);
```

Comment: can you post the `var_dump($event_json)`?

Comment: don't use `@` before `file_get...` unless you're sure you know what you're doing any *why* you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an associate array in PHP, you need to use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with two parameters: 1) being your `$input` 2) assoc which when set to true returns an associated array:

```
$event_json = json_decode($input, true);
print_r($event_json);
```

The way you want to get the data into variables is by using [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
extract($event_json);
```